# iphone programming - how to record a call

Tags: iphone, call, recording

Is there any API in iPhone SDK to record a call and play it later?

Answer (score 5):

No, that is "off limits".

Comment: Yeah, that's a service. As in, it's a VoIP application you put on your phone. I've not installed it, so I don't know if it's recording locally or on the server, but either way, it's not recording cellular calls, just VoIP calls.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not
you have to jailbreak your phone for this 
and use private API
because there is no public API for this...

but then apple will not accept your project
.......

Comment: Look at the app "CallRec.me" in itunes

Answer (score 0):

See [SpoofApp](http://www.spoofapp.com/) for jailbroken phones.